# How to calculate a 1D convolution summation?

Tags: convolution

I hope I said that right. I'm trying to follow along with a convolution example but maybe I am in over my head. I don't understand how in this example they get the values on the right. For example, I would think when n=0 the result would be 0*0 not 1*2.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something you might want to watch if you are having trouble with the convolution of two signals is the animation at 34:00 or so from this lecture from MIT Open Courseware: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TuCYGjp7WKU). The lecturer is Oppenheim, who co-wrote a classic book on discrete-time signal processing.

Comment: Wow that was cool thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

the 1 is x[0] and the 2 is h[0] which if you look at the impulse response h[0] is 2.
the 3 is x[1] and the 2 is h[0]

etc.